# Incovenience of avoiding duplicate code due to an if statement c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, code-duplication

I want to avoid duplicated code in this usecase

```
class A {
protected: 
  virtual void A1(const void* const s, const std::streamsize n) const;
  inline void A2(const void* const s, const std::streamsize n) const;
};

class B : public A {
private:
  const  char *a;

  void B1(const char *b) {
     if (!b) {
       return;
     }
     if (a < b) {
         A1(a, b-a);
     }
  }

  void B2(const char *b) {
      if (!b) {
       return;
      }
      if (a < b) {
         A2(a, b-a);
     };
  }
};
```

So, as you can see above in both `B1()` and `B2()` there is duplicate code (that check for `b`) except for the call inside that if (note that the if condition is the same). I think this `if`makes somehow inconvenient to extract a new method, but also I think it can be done using lambdas and/or templates. There is no point of interest on how `A1()` and `A2()` are implemented for this usecase.

**My question**: What is the best and simplest way to avoid this duplication of code ?

Comment: Separate the duplicated code out into another function.

Comment: I edited the post, I don't think it deserves to move that condition for `b` in another function.

Comment: What are you bothering about then? Not every code duplication of simple statements needs to (and should) be avoided.

Comment: Well, if it can be done easy, why not?

Comment: There's certainly no _"easy"_ way to simplify what you have more without introducing more complicated constructs. Not that I'd recommend that, but put the boiler plate stuff into a macro if that makes you happy.

Comment: Assuming `a` is a pointer, `a < b` requires `b` to be non-NULL, so you can remove your first `if` statement altogether.

Beyond that, whether you should somehow merge or template the functions depends on what they do and what you want your interface to be like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a function that accepts pointer to member to be executed

```
class B : public A {
private:
    const  char *a;
    using F = void(A::*)(const void* const, const std::streamsize) const;
    void RunFun(F f, const char *b) {
        if (!b) {
            return;
        }
        if (a < b) {
            (this->*f)(a, b-a);
        }

    }


    void B1(const char *b) {
        RunFun(&B::A1,b);
    }

    void B2(const char *b) {
        RunFun(&B::A2,b);
    }
};
```

Comment: My idea would have been to add a tag to dispatch instead of using a pointer. But this way its easier to read and saves the dispatch-if. +1

Comment: I have a question: Why is needed `this` in `(this->*f)(a, b-a)` and not only `f(a, b-a)` ?

Comment: Since it is pointer to member function you need to specify the object to use for calling this function by pointer

Comment: And in this case `this` is referring to object `A`, right ?

Comment: Actually this is of type B* and pointer also passed as pointer to member of B:: - but since the B does not implement A1 directly - the implementation used was taken from the base class A

Comment: Interestingly, while this avoids the code duplication the class still has exactly the same number of lines. So is this an improvement or not? It obviously doesn't reduce the amount of code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another (simplified) example, using lambda and `std::function`

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct A
 {
   virtual void A1 (char const * const b)
    { std::cout << b << "\n- A1 call" << std::endl; }

   void A2 (char const * const b)
    { std::cout << b << "\n- A2 call" << std::endl; }
 };

struct B : public A
 {
   const char * a;

   std::function<void(char const * const, void(A::*)(char const * const))>
      funcA { [this](char const * const b, void(A::*f)(char const * const))
       { if ( b && std::strlen(b) ) (this->*f)(b); } };

   void B1 (char const * b)
    { funcA(b, &A::A1); }

   void B2 (char const * b)
    { funcA(b, &A::A2); }
 };

int main ()
 {
   B b;

   b.B1("- B1 call");
   b.B2("- B2 call");
 }
```